# How Can I Transfer Files to a BusyBox machine with only ftpd, telnetd?

Tags: linux, busybox

I'm trying to send and receive files from a Linux machine running busybox. The following commands are enabled, and I can't use anything else:

> [, [[, ash, basename, brctl, cat, chmod, chpasswd, cp, date, echo, expr, fdisk, free, ftpd, ftpputimage, grep, halt, hostname, ifconfig, inetd, init, init, insmod, kill, killall, klogd, logger, login, logread, ls, lsmod, mdev, mkdir, mknod, mount, ping, ping6, poweroff, printf, ps, pwd, reboot, rm, rmmod, route, sed, sh, sleep, syslogd, telnetd, test, touch, udhcpc, udhcpd, umount, uptime, vconfig, vi, wc, zcip```.

I've tried to use `ftpd`, but I can't figure out how to use it and it displays this prompt:

> Usage: ftpd [-wvS] [-t N] [-T N] [DIR]

Any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have ssh access ?

Comment: No, I only have a telnet connection

Answer (score 0):

BusyBox's `ftpd` [documentation](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) tells you how to use it: configure it in /etc/inetd.conf

```
ftpd [-wvS] [-t N] [-T N] [DIR]

Anonymous FTP server

ftpd should be used as an inetd service. ftpd's line for inetd.conf: 21 stream tcp nowait root ftpd ftpd /files/to/serve It also can be ran from tcpsvd:

        tcpsvd -vE 0.0.0.0 21 ftpd /files/to/serve

Options:

    -w      Allow upload
    -v      Log to stderr
    -S      Log to syslog
    -t,-T   Idle and absolute timeouts
    DIR     Change root to this directory
```

But you also have telnet. With that, you can at the very least also communicate single files using for example `cat` and pipes.

Much more comfortable is if your kernel supports any network file systems. Then you can just mount e.g. a CIFS or NFS share.

Even if it doesn't - using a slightly awkward method like ftp or cat through telnet to put a statically linked ssh server like dropbear on your embedded device would make your life much easier. Or, drop a statically linked curl there that includes all the protocols you would want to use; that's also always a popular method of fetching more stuff.

Comment: I'll try this, thanks